# react-router-dom v6 upgrade

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

We're going through the process of updating various NPM packages and currently looking at react-router-dom v5 -> v6. The documentation is pretty good, but I cant see how to account for some changes in the **Route** component.

In v5 we had the following:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={`/reviewer/${reviewsMenuPath}/history/:acronym`}
    render={({ match }) => {
      const breadcrumbs = [
        { text: 'Reviews' },
        { text: 'History', link: `/reviewer/${reviewsMenuPath}/history` },
        { key: match.params.acronym }];
      return (
        <>
          <ComponentOne title="Your completed reviews" />
          <ComponentTwo
            acronym={match.params.acronym}
            key={match.params.acronym}
            breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}
          />
        </>
      );
    }}
  />
```

but 'render' is no longer available in v6. I understand the requirement for *Switch -> Routes* and that I'll need to introduce *element={}*, but am unsure how to construct the *breadcrumbs* data so that its available for *ComponentTwo*...would appreciate any suggestions and/or thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a wrapper component that reads the path params.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Breadcrumb = ({ reviewsMenuPath }) => {
  const { acronym } = useParams();

  const breadcrumbs = [
    { text: 'Reviews' },
    { text: 'History', link: `/reviewer/${reviewsMenuPath}/history` },
    { key: match.params.acronym }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne title="Your completed reviews" />
      <ComponentTwo
        acronym={acronym}
        key={acronym}
        breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route
    path={`/reviewer/${reviewsMenuPath}/history/:acronym`}
    element={<Breadcrumb reviewsMenuPath={reviewsMenuPath} />}
  />
  ...
</Routes>
```

Another alternative is to move the `useParams` and `const breadcrumbs` logic into `ComponentTwo`. This is easy and trivial if `ComponentTwo` is already a React Function component. If it is a Class component then you'd need to either convert it to a Function component or create a [custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) in order to access the `acronym` path parameter.